# Questions about IPv4Address in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am extracting informations from my Active Directory using Powershell with the command **Get-ADComputer** and I have some questions about a field in the result, this field is **IPv4Address**.

I haven't set any IPAdress in my active Directory and it is populated, so here are my questions :

- How Active Directory retrieve this information ?
- How often ?
- Is there any documentation related to all the properties that can be extracted from the Active Directory ? I cannot find any.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`How Active Directory retrieve this information?`

The PowerShell cmdlet performs a DNS lookup.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.
So, this is answering my Second question too !